# I need some help resolving db error:unknown error CSV Import helper when selecting a CSV from my desktop

Tags: contacts, import, data-import, csv

I prepared a CSV for upload. I'll have to make multiple passes on the upload  because I have single entry items and multiple  entry data in the spreadsheet. I have created all of my custom fields. I can do a standard contact import with the unsupervised rule.

I see that I need an ID number for the multi-record import. I installed the CSV Import Helper to prepare for the multi-record import. When I select the CSV (I'm using the ; for my field delimiter) I get the DB error: unknown error from CiviCRM.

I'm on WordPress with CiviCRM 5.20.1

The only error I see in the Civi error log is :

> [26-Feb-2020 16:20:05 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SERVER_NAME in /home/websiteweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/classes/class.km.autoupdate.v3.php on line 75
>
> [26-Feb-2020 16:20:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /home/websiteweb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php on line 364

My end goal is to merge the contact IDs into the data set so I can proceed. Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was unrelated to the log error, which we will debug at a future time.

The problem was caused by my preferred use of a semicolon ";" as a delimiter instead of a comma ",". I frequently use the semicolon because clients frequently include commmas in names and addresses. Apparently this disambiguation was a problem for the CSV Import Helper.